# Scrapy response does not contain all tables from URL using xpath

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having trouble scraping all the table footers in a URL ("https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aardsda01.shtml") using Scrapy in Python 3.7. I can see the first table (id=pitching_standard), but other tables such as batting_standard and standard_fielding do not appear in the response. The code is included below:

```
class BaseballRefSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "baseball"

    def start_requests(self):
        allowed_domains = ["baseball-reference.com"]
        start_urls = ["https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aardsda01.shtml"]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        tables = response.selector.xpath('//table[@id="batting_standard"]/tfoot')
        for table in tables:
            with open("/path_to_directory/tables.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write(table.get())
```

Comment: You can omit the selector (eg `response.xpath`). You search for table with the id of `battling_standard` so that's what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too versed in scrapy, but the issue is with the reference.com sites, some of the tables are within the comments of the html. So you need a way to pull out the comments, then parse those tables. Personally, I'd just pull out the table tags, and then manipulate the dataframes to get just the footer. But you can get the footer using beautifulsoup (I then let pandas parse that into a table, however requires you to either a) put that `<table>` tag in there, or b) pull the table tag and remove the `<tbody>`.

But here's to show you that you can get it with pulling out the comments:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aardsda01.shtml"
result = requests.get(url).text
data = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

comments = data.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            table = BeautifulSoup(each, 'html.parser').find('table', attrs = {'id': 'batting_standard'}).find('tfoot')
            if table != None:
                table = pd.read_html('<table>' + str(table))[0].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
        except:
            continue
```

**Output:**

```
print(table)
               0              1              2   ...   25   26   27
0           9 Yrs          9 Yrs          9 Yrs  ...  1.0  0.0  0.0
1   162 Game Avg.  162 Game Avg.  162 Game Avg.  ...  1.0  0.0  0.0
2             NaN            NaN            NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     SEA (2 yrs)    SEA (2 yrs)    SEA (2 yrs)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
4      NYM (1 yr)     NYM (1 yr)     NYM (1 yr)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
5      CHC (1 yr)     CHC (1 yr)     CHC (1 yr)  ...  1.0  0.0  0.0
6      SFG (1 yr)     SFG (1 yr)     SFG (1 yr)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
7      ATL (1 yr)     ATL (1 yr)     ATL (1 yr)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
8      BOS (1 yr)     BOS (1 yr)     BOS (1 yr)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
9      CHW (1 yr)     CHW (1 yr)     CHW (1 yr)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
10            NaN            NaN            NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN
11     AL (5 yrs)     AL (5 yrs)     AL (5 yrs)  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
12     NL (4 yrs)     NL (4 yrs)     NL (4 yrs)  ...  1.0  0.0  0.0

[13 rows x 28 columns]
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! Now that I know to look in the comments, I'll play around with scrapy and see if I can't make that work, too.